# String '==' and String pool behaviour

Tags: java, string

My question is simple. Whats the difference between -

`s3=s1+s2` and `s3="string"` ?

I think I was very poor in explaining it.

I do understand the difference between `==` and `.equals()`.

Comment: A string object is not the same as a string literal. A literal is something that directly appears in your program; `s3` does not store a literal, but the result of an operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A new `String` object will be created, when the concatenation of 2 objects take place. But if you concat 2 string literals, then a new object won't be created.

```
String s3=s1+s2; // new object created
System.out.println(s3=="string"); // false

String s4="str"+"ing"; // this will not create a new string object
System.out.println(s4=="string"); // true
```

When the compiler encounters `String s4="str"+"ing";`, the compiler does a constant folding on the compile-time constants and puts it into just one string, since the concatenation happens at compile time itself, and the completed string therefore goes in the constant pool.

Comment: +1. You might want to explain why it doesn't make a new object in the latter String.

Comment: String s3=s1+s2; // new object created and s3 references the new object in the String pool right?. i.e, to say s3 points to the result of s1+s2.. right?

Comment: Yeah, a new object is created and s3 references that. But in the case of s4, it references the string literal "string" which is already present in the constants pool.

Comment: @R.J Too bad I can't revote.. :)

Comment: Ya.. The edit helped.. Thanks.. But one more question... String s3=s1+s2; // new object created
System.out.println(s3=="string"); // false .. Here "string" is not going into the string pool??..

Comment: Nope. It goes to the heap. But if you manually call `s3 = s3.intern()`, it'll lookup for your string literal in the constants pool and if found, will return the reference to that. This way you can make `s3` refer to the literal present in the pool.

Answer (score 2):

`==` operator checks whether the references to the objects are equal.

`equals()` method checks whether the values of the objects are equal.

For comparing strings use [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

```
System.out.println(s3.equals("string"));
```

Comment: My question is simple... Whats the difference between - s3=s1+s2 and s3="string" ?

Comment: My apologies.. But that's not my question.. My question is what's the difference between the 2 statements.. BTW I understand the difference between == and .equals().

Answer (score 1):

`s3` is a new `String` object that is the concatenation of `s1` and `s2`

`==` will compare their memory addresses. not their literal values. use `.equals()`

Answer (score 1):

> The function == checks whether the object of the to are the same.
>
> Here the content is same but the objects are not same .

Look [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/767379/1844148) for a the difference between == and .equals

Answer (score 0):

== is used on primitive types. On object you should use compare or equals. Strings are treatenin a particular way. Because == on strings doesn't alsways work fine is due by the concatenating of them by the jvm. It takes only the reference to the strings, == checks the memory location.

Comment: `==` is used on objects, to check if they are the same instance. On objects one should use `equals` when one wants to check if two objects have the "same content" as defined by the particular implementation of `equals` on those objects (and if the objects don't override `equals`, `Object.equals` is used which just compares using `==` anyway).